# Specification of efi-directory and device in grub-install

Tags: boot, grub

I have this layout of my USB flash disk:

```
+---------------+  +----------------+
|               |  |                |
| EFI partition |  | data partition |
|               |  |                |
+---------------+  +----------------+
[media]$ mount /dev/sda1 ./efi
[media]$ mount /dev/sda2 ./data

[media]$ grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck --boot-directory=data/boot /dev/sda
[media]$ grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --recheck --removable --efi-directory=efi/ --boot-directory=data/boot /dev/sda
```

This gives me the option to boot from legacy and UEFI modes.

The grub configuration files will be stored in data/boot.

1) Why do I have to specify the device after `--boot-directory`?

2) Why do I have to specify `--efi-directory` in second `grub-install` and what does it mean?

I will be glad of progress how does it boot, what is loaded first etc.

Thanks for it!

Answer (score 1):

### Why do I have to specify the device after `--boot-directory`?

You can install GRUB into the MBR of one disk (`/dev/sda`), with the configuration data in the directory `/boot` on that disk. Allegedly, you could chose a `boot` directory on a different disk, too.
As for the parameter position: It is quite common to have optional parameters prefixed with `--` and coming before the obligatory parameters.

### Why do I have to specify `--efi-directory` in second `grub-install` and what does it mean?

With EFI-style-booting, the boot-loader is not located in the MBR or any other known "magic" physical location on the disk. The boot-loader is actually stored in a file on a mounted file-system (usually FAT32) of the special "EFI System Partition". `grub-install` needs to know where to find this file-system.

For both, the boot-directory and the efi-directory, it would be possible for `grub-install` to guess and find them automagically, but it is more reliable just to tell it where to find them.

PS: I have a USB flash disk like this, too. Came in handy many times. :)